# Javascript: The text node

Tags: javascript

I am using the following piece from W3school site. When I used the LI element in a straight line, it works fine. Bus as I put it in a format it doesn't work. Does someone has any clue?

This does not work:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
<p>Click the button to replace the first item in the the list.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
    var item = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0];
    item.replaceChild(textnode, item.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
```

This works:

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>

<p>Click the button to replace the first item in the the list.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
    var item = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0];
    item.replaceChild(textnode, item.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'does not work'? What error gives you?

Answer (score 0):

1) `childNodes` is problematic, since it does not only count the nodes you visually see, but also whitespace nodes and comment nodes. For the following example:

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>
```

`childNodes.length` would return 3 (for your 3 element `li` nodes), but in this example (which produces the exact same HTML output on your screen!):

```
<ul id="myList2">
   <!-- a comment node -->
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

`childNodes.length` would return 9! (5 whitespace nodes (type:TEXT_NODE), 1 comment node and 3 element nodes). That's why a Node element has a [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) attribute, which you can check to determine the type. But you probably want to use [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) instead of `childNodes`.

2) The simplest solutions are sometimes the best. I would take a straight forward approach:

```
document.querySelector("#myList li:first-of-type").innerHTML = "Water"
```

See the [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtmk790x/) (watch the console output).

3) Inline events are discouraged, it's better to attach events to nodes by binding them in the js via `addEventListener`.

Instead of

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

use

```
<button id="some-id">Try it</button>

<script>
   document.getElementById("some-id").addEventListener(myFunction);
<script>
```

4) Despite what the name would imply, W3Schools is not affiliated with the w3c and also, due to a lot of negative experience in the past, not seen as a very reputable source for information about webdevelopment. They have improved lately, but I still would not choose it as my primary source of information. See also http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Thank you. What you said, it make sense and also I thought that they including carriage return and spaces as nodes.